Logistic regression resulting in "eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1"?
Keep in mind that I'm very new to regression (not necessarily R as a language, but I'm no expert). I am using a data set called MidCity and I am supposed to determine whether or not brick homes are more expensive than homes without brick. I'm attempting this by using logistic regression (glm(Price ~ Brick, data = mc, family = "binomial")) but I keep getting the error message Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1. My y-values (Brick) in the original data started as "Yes"/"No" strings, but I changed those to binary using ifelse(mc$Brick == "Yes", 1, 0) and it is listed as binary in the dataframe itself, but I am still getting this error. If I remove the family = "binomial" as an argument, the code runs but it (obviously) performs a linear regression. I am supposed to be comparing logistic and linear regressions in this assignment so I can't choose to only use linear; I have to use both.
I'll attach my code and the first 20 rows of the data, plus the two relevant columns, in case that's helpful:
library(glmnet)

# read in data
mc = structure(list(Brick = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), Price = c(114300L, 114200L, 114800L, 
94700L, 119800L, 114600L, 151600L, 150700L, 119200L, 104000L, 
132500L, 123000L, 102600L, 126300L, 176800L, 145800L, 147100L, 
83600L, 111400L, 167200L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

# change "Yes"/"No" strings to binary
mc$Brick = ifelse(mc$Brick == "Yes", 1, 0)

# plot datapoints
plot(x = mc$Brick, y = mc$Price, main = "Logistic/Linear Regression", xlab = "Brick Home (No = 0; Yes = 1)", ylab = "Price ($)", col = "purple")

# logistic regression model
logreg_brick = glm(Price ~ Brick, data = mc, family = "binomial") # removing family = "binomial" 
# causes the code to run, but I get a linear regression instead of a logistic regression

# summarize
print(summary(logreg_brick), show.residuals = TRUE)

# add prediction to plot
curve(predict(logreg_brick, data.frame(Brick = x), type = "resp"), add = TRUE, col = "red", lw = 5)

# linear regression model
linreg_brick = lm(Price ~ Brick, data = mc)

# summarize
print(summary(linreg_brick), show.residuals = TRUE)

# add prediction to plot
curve(predict(linreg_brick, data.frame(Brick = x), type = "resp"), add = TRUE, col = "blue", lw = 2)

Also note that I tried switching mc$Price and mc$Brick in the glm() call so that it's glm(Brick ~ Price, ...) and that did work, but the coefficients were super tiny and clearly incorrect.
TIA :)

Why are you attempting logistic regression? That would only make sense if your dependent variable (price) was binary.

I believe variable Price (the "y" in your formula) is not binary?

If Price is your outcome, and if you really want to do logistic regression on this outcome, then you'll have to "cut" it into two pieces (high vs low price), perhaps using the median or some other well-chosen value.

On the face of it, it doesn't make much sense to do a logistic regression of price on house type, as others mentioned; maybe your instructor is thinking you should turn it around and look at house type as a function of price, and do a kind of round about inference that if price is significant for classifying house type, then house type is equally relevant for estimating price ... I'm just making stuff up here, you should probably ask what they're expecting you to do. Interesting, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com for followups.

@RobertDodier So if I'm understanding right, I can use logistic regression to determine how much the price of a house affects whether the house is brick or not? And that's why the coefficients for logistic regression are so small (because 0 and 1 are indicators of whether the house is brick or not)?
I guess I assumed that as long as one of my variables was binary and categorical, I could use logistic regression regardless of independent/dependent. Thank you for the clarification! I'll ask my professor what he means by "does the premium change based on which model you fit and why" :)

Well, just to be clear, I was trying to make a justification after the fact -- trying to sort out some way the question could make sense. Since you can ask your professor, you should probably go ahead and do that. Be careful to say "X is associated with Y" rather than "X affects Y" or "X causes Y" when you talk about regression models of any kind. Also, remember a logistic regression is a model for p(c|x) where c is a class (0 or 1) and x is a continuous variable (or at least ordinal, if you wave your hands). So the target or output has to be a 0/1 variable.
